# kde5: Note widget disappeared. How can I get it back?

Tags: kde, kde5

My computer freezed and after a restart, all my notes are gone. The notes are still in the folder `/.local/share/plasma_notes`

When I try to add a new widget, I don't find the note widget in the widget panel anymore. Where is it gone? And how can I get it back?

For example: I can't find the note widget in this panel widget anymore.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by Tosky from the KDE-Forum: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=151054&p=394700

A package was missing: plasma-widgets-addons